# Не работает код. Ошибку не выдает. При заходе пользователя на сервер роль не выдается и ничего не пишется в чат

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os, sqlite3
from discord import utils


import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(952188797884448778)

    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=952180184444989521)
    print ('user join the servers')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{member.name} присоиединился', color = 0x0c0c0c))

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print ('user join the servers')
    channel = client.get_channel(952188797884448778)
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=952180184444989521)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'{member.name} присоиединился', color=0x0c0c0c))

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```